# How to determine server disconnection from SignalR client?

Tags: javascript, long-polling, signalr

How can a SignalR JavaScript client detect when a connection with the server is lost?

Comment: Do you use signalr with asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided answers will no longer work.
This is the new way to stop/disconnect connections.

```
myHub.stop().then(() => {
  alert('Server has disconnected');
});
```

Answer (score 33):

A hub has a method `disconnect` which will allow you to add a callback when disconnection takes place:

```
myHub.disconnect(function() {
  alert('Server has disconnected');
});
```

If you aren't using hubs then the code for the disconnect method will help you out:

```
$(connection).bind("onDisconnect", function (e, data) {
  callback.call(connection);
});
```

This shows the syntax for hooking onto the onDisconnect event of the underlying connection.

Comment: Don't use bind... just do connection.disconnected

Comment: The proper method for this is now `$.connection.hub.disconnected(callback)`

Answer (score 13):

If you are using hubs then implement the IDisconnect interface.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub, IDisconnect
{
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId + " disconnected");
    }
}
```

On persistent connections you can override OnDisconnectAsync,
(from the SignalR wiki at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection )

```
public class MyEndPoint : PersistentConnection 
{
    protected override Task OnDisconnectAsync(string clientId) 
    {
        return Connection.Broadcast("Client " + clientId + " disconncted");   
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually very useful as an answer unrelated to the question, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The SignalR 2.0 way of doing this is like so:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    console.log('Connection disconnected')
});
```

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me using `"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.0"` npm package

```
const connection = new signalr.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('url')
    .configureLogging(signalr.LogLevel.Information)
    .build()

connection.onclose(() => {
   // close logic goes here
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting with SignalR v0.5.1 it works this way:

```
$.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (change) {
    if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.reconnecting) {
        console.log("liveFeed is reconnecting!");
    }
    else if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
        console.log("liveFeed is connected!");
    }
});
```

For more details check this website:

http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/06/10/signalr-0-5-1-released.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The below, worked for me:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('signalrConnectionUrl');

connection.disconnected(function() {
    console.log('Connection disconnected');
});
```

I'm using version: 2.1.2

See the following link for reference: [Link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime)