# Detect lost connection from SignalR Core connection

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, connection, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to detect when a SignalR Core connection is lost so that I can create a new one or at least warn the user.

```
connection.on('closed', data => {
    alert('Connection Closed');
});
```

This seems to have no effect. The messages stop arriving but this handler isn't fired.

On a related note, where is the documentation for event handling for the new version of this library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine server disconnection from SignalR client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101053/how-to-determine-server-disconnection-from-signalr-client)

Comment: A Quick Google search led me to find this [MS Doc - Handling Connection Livetime Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)

Comment: But the new Core version has a different API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `onclose`:

```js
connection.onclose(function (e) {
    alert('Connection Closed');
}
```

There's no documentation yet, but a handful of [samples](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/tree/dev/samples) on GitHub.

Comment: When does it fire? If I shut down my web server, the page seems none the wiser.

Comment: Ian Warburton, it seems to take awhile, but it does occur. I'm trying to figure this out too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot [aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8601760/aaron)!!

I know it's old, but maybe it will help someone new to SignalR.

I found the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and some example to reconnect it

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/chathub")
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
};

connection.onclose(async () => {
    await start();
});

// Start the connection.
start();
```