# Client Lifecycle events in ASP.NET Core SignalR

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm currently upgrading a project from [ASP.NET SignalR 2.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/2.2.3) (OWIN) to [ASP.NET Core SignalR 1.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/1.0.2) (Kestrel).

SignalR 2.2.3 supported several client sided [lifetime events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime) like `reconnecting`, `connectionSlow`, `stateChanged`, ... .
Our javascript client used those events and displayed something like "Reconnecting" or "Connection is currently slow".

Are there or will there be equivalents in ASP.NET Core SignalR? I only found two lifetime events so far:

```
let c = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().("/signalR");
c.connection.onClose(function(error) {});
c.connection.onReceive(function(data) {});
```

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49864154/333404), but the user only asked for the `onClose` event.

And no, I'm not looking for server sided [lifetime events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.1#handle-events-for-a-connection).

#### Update - Reconnect events

Okay since there is no reconnect (yet?) according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-reconnects) and this [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1057), I'm okay with the missing `Reconnecting` and `Reconnected`. But what about `connectionSlow`, `starting` and `stateChanged`?

Comment: May Be this link could help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926555/how-to-use-signalr-events-to-keep-connection-alive-in-the-right-way

Comment: Thx @AymenRagguem for your comment, but the mentioned SignalR in your linked SO question is a quite old version of SignalR (.NET 4.x era). I was specifically asking for the new .NET Core version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like currently there are only 2 states for a [HubConnection](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/master/clients/ts/signalr/src/HubConnection.ts):

- Disconnected
- Connected

Those states are exposed through a `state` property in the connection but there are no states for anything else.

However, there is an `ILogger` instance that is used prominently throughout the standard operations. A custom `ILogger` can be provided to the [HubConnectionBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/master/clients/ts/signalr/src/HubConnectionBuilder.ts) via the `configureLogging` method. You can use your custom logger to capture all the individual events and react accordingly.